# Dynamically generated html doesn't contain />, but > instead

Tags: jquery, dynamic, xhtml

I am generating html-content with jquery, but it won't generate />. It generates > instead.

```
$("#myDiv").append('<img src="nothing.jpg" alt="image" />');

this generates:

<img src="nothing.jpg" alt="image">

as you can see it has no />, but > instead
```

[Example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLSKW/)

Because of this, i can't get it through the XHTML validator.

It there any way to generate /> ?

If not, is it a big deal if i don't have it?

Comment: Are you sure it is not there? Because chrome doesnt show every `</>` in his console.

Comment: img is a self closing tag

Comment: No. `img` is an EMPTY element so it will never have any child nodes. In XHTML that means you can always represent it with self-closing tag syntax (but you don't have to … unless you are writing HTML-compatible XHTML (which is a pain and why I no longer write XHTML for 99% of things)). In HTML it means that the end tag is forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery won't generate HTML. It will modify the DOM.

You might then use `innerHTML` (possibly via `jQuery(...).html()`) or a DOM inspector to serialize the DOM to HTML.

If you are in HTML mode (i.e. the document was served as `text/html`) then you will get HTML out.

Browsers might give you XHTML if you serve the document as XHTML (i.e. with `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`), but they don't provide a way to generate XHTML when in HTML mode.

> If not, is it a big deal if i don't have it?

It's a huge deal. The markup won't be well formed and XML parsers will throw an error and stop.

I'd recommend using HTML instead of XHTML.

If you want to target XML parsers, then generate HTML and pass it to something server side that can parse HTML and output XHTML.

Comment: Thanks for your clear response. I tried to build my website in XHTML, and is was a pain in the butt from the beginning. I'll go back to HMTL, since the pros don't outweigh the cons anymore.